# CLOB issue over DB link with Oracle

Tags: oracle

Why can I run this in SQL Developer no issue.

```
INSERT INTO gtt_argus_narratives (
            case_id,
            abbrev_narrative,
            deleted,
            narrative,
            abbrev_narrative_j,
            narrative_j,
            dlp_revision_number,
            effective_start_date,
            effective_end_date,
            deleted_flag,
            enterprise_id
        ) 
            SELECT case_id,
            abbrev_narrative,
            deleted,
            narrative,
            abbrev_narrative_j,
            narrative_j,
            dlp_revision_number,
            effective_start_date,
            effective_end_date,
            deleted_flag,
            enterprise_id
        FROM ARGUS_INTEGRATION.DLP_CASE_NARRATIVE@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB
        WHERE CASE_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID FROM GT_ARGUS_LOCKS_TO_PROCESS);
```

Where NARRATIVE is a CLOB.

But if I put this into a procedure to execute as part of a bigger process, I get this:

```
Error(563,13): PL/SQL: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

Seems I have to wrap it into an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE so Oracle doesn't stop it compiling...

Interestingly if I do a join to a local GTT, it fails even with EXECUTE immediate.

```
FROM ARGUS_INTEGRATION.DLP_CASE_NARRATIVE@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB A
        INNER JOIN GT_ARGUS_LOCKS_TO_PROCESS B ON A.CASE_ID = B.CASE_ID AND A.DLP_REVISION_NUMBER = B.DLP_REVISION_NUMBER
```

If I do an IN statement, rather than a join in the where clause, it doesn't complain.

Comment: You should be able to do this even from within a stored procedure. Perhaps you are doing something different in your procedure, or combining this with more query parts, or attempting to fetch the results from a cursor? Those could all produce different behavior. if you can show the PL/SQL where this is used and any references to the CLOB column you are making in any cursor loop, that'd help.

Comment: no cursors, just put the same insert statement into the flow of the procedure

Comment: still, we aren't seeing the actual code you are running when you get the error. also, what version of Oracle on the target DB and the source DB?

Comment: The code is the code above but in a procedure, I doubt you want the 1700 lines of SQL, it complains that this is the line where the issue us

Comment: Create a reproducible test case with a dummy procedure, with minimal code needed to produce the error, and share it here. Also I need those DB versions. Oracle has changed its LOB handling over links over the years, it can get dicey in older versions.

Comment: Version is 19C.

Comment: On both sides? Local and remote?

Comment: its the join, if I do an "IN" statement instead of joining to a GTT on the local side, it doesn't complain.  Updated the question with this comment.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out on your own. LOBs over links are touchy, you have to figure out what works sometimes by trial and error. A changed execution plan can make the difference, depending on which direction it ships rows.

Comment: @PaulW LOBs over DBLINKs suck